# APC only half works

Tags: php, apc

I'm trying to get APC to work as a persistent data structure.

I wrote a test script to illustrate the problem I'm running into.

```
<?php
    function set_true()
    {
        apc_store("test", true);
        var_dump(apc_fetch("test"));
    }

    var_dump(apc_fetch("test"));
    set_true();
?>
```

When I try it with `apc.enable_cli=1`, the following occurs:

```
$ php test_store.php
bool(false)
bool(true)
$ php test_store.php
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

That is to say, the cache seems to be wiped between each session. This make sense according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.enable-cli).

As for when I run it without `apc.enable_cli=1`, the following occurs:

```
$ php test_store.php
bool(false)
bool(false)
$ php test_store.php
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

which is to say that the cache doesn't even exist throughout the entire script (storing isn't working).

I'd like to be able to affect one singular cache which remains stored throughout the life of the server, including accesses from a client accessing PHP, including scripts I write and run from the command line, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apc.enable_cli` means that it will work in CLI, but doesn't mean that it will persist values between requests (since there is just no appropriate storage for that).

So with `apc.enable_cli` it will keep the data during script run. Without it won't store it at all.

So if you really need caching - use another caching mechanism (memcached/files/...)

Comment: Just to be clear, this basically means that CLI makes a very temporary cache for the script and deletes it, but the CGI performance is unaffected (if run by CGI, it will persist), but there's no way to connect the CGI cache with the CLI cache? I just tried this by hosting it and running it through the client, and it appears to persist properly.

Comment: @River Tam: through what client? `APC` needs some shared memory to persist its data. And I'm not sure I believe it works in `CGI`. Is it pure cgi or something else?

Comment: Client meaning through the browser accessing the server (a php script served up through apache). That is, I'm trying to get APC to work a bit more like a really lightweight database than a cache, so I want to be able to edit the data from both the client and the server.

Comment: @River Tam: "through apache" doesn't mean using CGI. In case if it's `mod_php` - there is a shared memory allocated by apache's module that can be used for storing data. Use memcached to get what you want